# Merged accounts don't show correct post count on network profile?

Tags: bug, merge-accounts, sock-puppets, network-profile

Not a big issue, but it seems the network profile counts might be off when accounts are merged.

Example: for some time (about a week, possibly longer), a [merged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399743/swilsonmc) account has been showing only 1 question [on the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1389385/swilsonmc?tab=accounts) ([merged](https://stackexchange.com/users/1471979/)):

[image]

...while in fact [there's an upvoted answer too](https://superuser.com/users/127240/swilsonmcss):

[image]

Maybe things are fixed when there's activity; in the example the merged account is actually suspended as well.

Comment: Seems like a common accounts listing glitch that will normally get fixed once another event occurs on the affected site, which won't happen for a year because they're suspended. ;P

Comment: Caching? I'd expect these values to be synched at most every hour if not over a longer time frame.

Comment: True, @ChrisF, but the accounts have been merged for more than a week.