# Merging Accounts didn't merge number of questions on Network Profile

Tags: bug, network-profile, merge-accounts

I  while back I merged an old Lifehacks account with my main account. Before the merge, I asked one question using my old account.

The correct amount of questions are shown in my lifehacks [account activity](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/7500/tot-zam) summary:

> [image]

Yet it still displays "0" Questions on my [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5924590/tot-zam?tab=accounts).

> [image]

The accounts were merged over 5 months ago and I have since answered 2 questions, so this doesn't seem to be just an update delay or a delay till other activity occurs.

---

Similar questions have been asked, yet none seem to have a relevant solution:
[Merged accounts don't show correct post count on network profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134247/merged-accounts-dont-show-correct-post-count-on-network-profile) - the only comment possibly helpful seems to indicate that this problem should be fixed as soon as there is other activity in the account. I have since answered 2 other questions so there has been activity.
[Question not appearing on network profile (probably due to account merging)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196897/question-not-appearing-on-network-profile-probably-due-to-account-merging) - in this case, it seems to have been a one time reindexing delay error.

Comment: It seems only to update when you ask a question.