# Network Profile cached files don't update for all events

Tags: feature-request, bug, network-profile, caching

#### The problem:

Two years ago, I asked a question on User Experience that received 13 upvotes:
[For death year, should I use N/A or --- if person still alive?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/86756/for-death-year-should-i-use-n-a-or-if-person-still-alive)

Six months ago, a user was removed, and the upvote count went down to 12:

> [image: removed]

As you can see, the upvote count on the question page was changed to 12:

> [image: Question page 12 count]

On my [Network Profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/5924590/tot-zam), however, the count still says 13:

> [image: Network Profile 13 count]

I've had similar issues before with the Network Profile numbers being off, and I'm wondering if these issues are all one big problem of the Network Profile cached files not updating for all events:
[Network Profile showing wrong answer count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298908/network-profile-showing-wrong-answer-count)
[Merging Accounts didn't merge number of questions on Network Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269081/merging-accounts-didnt-merge-number-of-questions-on-network-profile)

It seems like these cached files only updates for two events. All question counts only update when a question is voted on. All answer counts only update when an answer is voted on.

I understand that cached files help pages load faster, and I'm okay with updates being delayed for let's say 24 hour. However, if no event happens after a mess up occurs that triggers an update, the wrong numbers remain for months, or even years.

#### Can we fix this?

I don't know the best way to fix these mismatched numbers, but one idea is to refresh all cached files every x amount of hours or days. This would catch and fix all changes that happened from events like account merging and user removal.

Another option would be to add more events to the list of actions that trigger the cached files update. If this idea is used though, a one time script would still need to run to fix all files that are already messed up. It also might be hard to figure out the list of all actions that can possibly affect the number counts.

Comment: How about not removing reputation from a users' votes 6+ months ago when they are removed?

Comment: @LiamHealy too bad if the user is not removed by request